# Select Clause In LINQ Query

Tags: c#, linq

Can Anyone Tell Me that: 
How Many Types of `Select` Clause available in `LINQ` Query and How it affect on Performance as `Select` Varies?

Examples I Found :

**1. That using New Class To Get the Objects from Tables**

```
class DogInformation {
   public string Name {get;set;}
   public string BreedName {get;set;}
}

var result = (from a in new DataContext().Dogs                 
              select new DogInformation { a.Name, a.BreedName }).ToList();
```

**2. Using Anonymous Type**

```
var result = from d in db.Dogs
                 join b in db.Breeds on d.BreedId equals b.BreedId
                 select new
                        {
                            Name = d.Name,
                            BreedName = b.BreedName
                        };
    return result.ToList();
```

**3. Another I Found is**

```
var result = (from d in db.Dogs
             join b in db.Breeds on d.BreedId equals b.BreedId
             select new
                    {
                        Name = d.Name,
                        BreedName = b.BreedName
                    }).ToList()
                      .Select(x=> 
                          new Dog{
                              Name = x.Name,
                              BreedName = x.BreedName,
                          }).ToList();
return result;
```

Comment: It depends upon what you call different types, because 1 and 3 are the same semantics.

Comment: Thanks for cmnt, Do we have more then this three?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, in linq, you've got two syntaxes :

- query syntax
- method syntax (extension methods)

so you can do

```
//query syntax
from item in <yourEnumerable> 
select ...
```

or

```
//method syntax
<yourEnumerable>.Select(m => xxx
```

now in both syntax, you can either project to an anonymous type or a strong type.

which is

```
  //A1. query syntax and anonymous
   select new {Id = item.a, Name = item.b}
  //A2. query syntax and strong type
  select new Test{Id = item.a, Name = item.b}
  //B1. method syntax and anonymous
  .Select(m => new {Id = m.a, Name = m.b});
  //B2. method syntax and strong type
  .Select(m => new {Test{Id = m.a, Name = m.b});
```

I'm almost certain that there's no perf difference between query and method syntax.

Now, difference between anonymous and strong type is usually not a problem of perf, it's a problem of needs...

Answer (score 2):

Hi alpesh you could find useful examples in http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b.

Answer (score 1):

Glancing at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384087.aspx), the only other `select` that will give you records is where you already have them like `select a`.

BTW VB.NET has `Select Name=d.Name, BreedName=b.BreedName`, but that's just an even more anonymous type.